# Normal distribution question in terms of k

Tags: probability

if X is a normally distributed random variable and $ P( X \le x) = k $ find $ P( X \le 2\mu - x) $ in terms of k.

I tried standardizing the variable but don't know how 1-k is obtained as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is symmetric about $\mu$ i.e. $P(X\leq \mu-x)=P(X\geq \mu+x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$. $P(X\leq 2\mu-x)=P(X\leq \mu-(x-\mu))=P(X\geq \mu+(x-\mu))=P(X\geq x)=1-k$